# validating a field is present only if it belongs to other table row

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model where there is a field that can be null and "has and belongs to many relation". The field name is `pms_ink_heat_transfer` and relation is to `style_method` table.

How can I make `pms_ink_heat_transfer` required only if it belongs to `Heat Transfer` row of table `style_method`?

Where `Heat Transfer` is the field of column `name` in `style_method`.

My model:

```
     class Color < ApplicationRecord
       has_and_belongs_to_many :style_methods
       // Insert validation here
     end
```

To give you a much better idea. Here is my code on active admin:

```
  f.input :pms_ink_heat_transfer
  f.input :style_methods, as: :check_boxes,collection:StyleMethod.order('name')
```

Therefor I need to make `pms_ink_heat_transfer` compulsory if the checkbox of collection is checked for `heat transfer` (one of the field in StyleMethod)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if I got your data structure right, but you can validate it conditionally in your model like this:

```
validates :pms_ink_heat_transfer, :presence => true, if: -> 
{ self.style_method.try(:name).to_s == 'Heat Transfer' }
```

also, consider validating it in client side too using something like jquery validations for better user experience.

Hope this helps, good luck!